# Get column values from mapping tables "id | value" binding

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get all the columns associated to with my item, some columns are "key | value" paired and that's where my problem is. My idea for a structure looks like this

[image]

I can retrieve 1 item from Posts along with all associated tag names with this query, but the problem is that I just can get 1 post

```
SELECT TOP(10)
    bm.title, bm.post_id, 
    a.name AS tag1, b.name AS tag2, c.name AS tag3, d.name AS tag4
FROM            
    Posts AS bm 
INNER JOIN 
    Tagmap AS tm 
INNER JOIN 
    Tag AS a ON a.tag_id = tm.tag_id1 
INNER JOIN 
    Tag AS b ON b.tag_id = tm.tag_id2 
INNER JOIN 
    Tag AS c ON c.tag_id = tm.tag_id3 
INNER JOIN 
    Tag AS d ON d.tag_id = tm.tag_id4 
    ON bm.post_id = tm.post_id
```

[image]

Here is the DDL for the table, or you can get it from this  [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/21PxMsjQ) link:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tag 
(
    tag_id int NOT NULL identity(0,1) primary key,
    name nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
);
 
CREATE TABLE Tagmap 
(
    id int NOT NULL identity(0,1) primary key,
    post_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(post_id),
    tag_id1 int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tag(tag_id),
    tag_id2 int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tag(tag_id),
    tag_id3 int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tag(tag_id),
    tag_id4 int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tag(tag_id)
);
 
CREATE TABLE Posts 
(
    post_id int NOT NULL identity(0,1) primary key,
    title nvarchar(50) not null,
);
 
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES ('Title1');
INSERT INTO Posts VALUES ('Title2');
INSERT INTO Tag VALUES ('Tag number one');
INSERT INTO Tag VALUES ('Tag number two');
INSERT INTO Tag VALUES ('Tag number three');
INSERT INTO Tag VALUES ('Tag number four');

INSERT INTO Tagmap VALUES (0, 0, 1, 2, 3);
```

My question: is my approach totally off? Should I change the structure or is it good?

If so how can it be better and how can I retrieve all these "key | value" columns along with my posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should fix your data structure, so you have one row in `tagMap` per `post_id` and `tag_id` -- not four!

But event with your current structure, I imagine that not all posts have four tags.  So, with your current data model you should be using `LEFT JOIN`, rather than `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Good feedback, one row in tagMap per post_id and tag_id souns like a bettar approach. . I was way off thanks for pointing in the right direction